# DFS on each node of the graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

Let's say in my directed graph G = (V, E), I have nodes which have certain numbers assigned to it, n[v]. I want to find the highest n[v] for each vertex, that is max(n[v]) means the maximum n[v] of the node reachable from each vertex in G.
What would we the efficient to solve this?
I am thinking on the lines of DFS on each node without backtracking and comparing the n[v] for all the 'visited' nodes and storing the maximum n[v] value for that path.
However, I am afraid that this might not be the efficient solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think this is inefficient?

If you run DFS on all source nodes (nodes that only out edges and no edges coming in) you are guaranteed to visit all nodes.

You can easily store the max(n[v]) on a node only after you visit all of its children.

And then if you reach a node that already has a max(n[v]) after starting from another source, you know you don't have to continue exploring that nodes children because the value is only assigned once you've visited all the children.

You're doing this in ~|E| steps (unless you have isolated nodes with no in our out edges) since you'll travel each edge exactly once.

I guess if you want to be super accurate you'll be doing this in |E| + |S| steps where |S| is the number of source nodes in your graph.

This seems to be pretty efficient to me. I'm not sure if it's possible to get a deterministic answer without checking every edge at least once.

Edit:

Also, I guess if you want to be extra complete, you may need to run a pre-step of checking all V nodes to determine which are source nodes. AND THEN running DFS on only source nodes.

So overall if would be |V| + |E| + |S| steps which is O(|V| + |E|)

Comment: It would be inefficient because I will have to invoke DFS on each node in a connected component, which I might already have traveled. Also, what if there is only one source node?

Comment: No, you would only have to invoke DFS on the source nodes. I also think you may be overlooking this part of my answer: "And then if you reach a node that already has a max(n[v]) after starting from another source, you know you don't have to continue exploring that nodes children because the value is only assigned once you've visited all the children"

Comment: And if there's only one source node then you are guaranteed to visit all the other nodes off one invocation of DFS. If there are more, you can be more efficient by stopping the DFS down a certain path if that node already has a max(n[v]) assigned to it if you do it the way i described.

Comment: I had missed some of your points. Thanks! It seems to work well :)

Comment: Glad I can help. Also if this answer helped you (and probably all answers you do in the future) could you kindly accept the answer as correct. (click on the little checkmark to the left of the answer)